# Forge API server location

Tags: server, location

we have a client with a requirement for UK governmental level of security.

consequently when using the forge API to view auto CAD drawings, we need to know where  their data is sent/received.

I understand their options for server locations in the UK and EU but  can anyone tell me whether we can specifically request UK locations or we are able to host these services ourselves within the UK.

Any guidance much appreciated – thanks

We asked the question of Autodesk support – still waiting for an answer